# Extract 1st letter from cell concatenate with another cell paste in third cell, then next row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract 1st letter from cell `B2` concatenate with cell `C2` paste in cell `A2`,
then move to next row and repeat till last data row.

I have the following, which partially works, but only works for the first row A2 then fills down this one string through all the rows till last data row.

```
Sub UserName()

Dim rng As range
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = .range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    rng.Value = fUserName(rng.Value)
Next
End Sub
```

The function

```
Function fUserName(ByVal strUserName As String) As String

Dim r As String

r = range("B2").Select
strUserName = Left(Trim(r), 1) & " " & range("C2")

fUserName = strUserName
End Function
```

Comment: 100% that this is not the correct context to use VBA such as this - start with formulas and if it really can't be achieved that way then hit the VBA. Peterm has made a start for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. I have combined both your procedure.
**No need of using a function , No need of For each loop**

```
Sub UserName()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Range("A1:A" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "= left(RC[1],1) & RC[2]"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, after I slept on it I realized that was not a sensible way to approch this, I will study what you wrote I seem to have a need in my automating process for things like this.  Thanks again.  Tim

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you don't need VBA for that. Just use formula in `A2`

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(B2, 1),C2)
```

And then just replicate it for all cells that contain data.

Comment: I agree. That's what I would do. I based my answer on VBA because that's what the OP asked but your solution is what I would go for personnally.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I am trying to automate a process that has to be repeated over and over so I wanted a vba solution.  Tim

Answer (score 1):

Your function is wrong, you are passing strUserName to the function but then setting the same variable within the function, however the real source of your issue is that you are using static references in your function so it does not matter which cell your sub routine is dealing with the function looks a cells B2 and C2.

I would get rid of the function all together and just replace the line

```
rng.Value = fUserName(rng.Value)
```

With

```
rng.Value = Left(Trim(rng.offset(0,1)), 1) & " " & rng.offset(0,2)
```

If you really want to use a function you need to pass the range to the function, not the value of the active cell as this has no bearing on the values of the other cells around it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments helped me understand were I went wrong.  Tim

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the range into the function:

```
Sub UserName()

Dim rng As range
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = .range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    rng.Value = fUserName(rng)
Next

End Sub

Function fUserName(rn as Range) As String  
    fUserName = Left(Trim(rn(1,2).value), 1) & " " & rn(1,3).value
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for straightening this out for me, I have asked alot of questions lately and was trying my hand at writing something on my own (mostly just altering something that Santosh had given me in another question) clearly I was not being very sensible.  Tim

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously B2 and C2 are hardcoded values so they do not change. You need to make those change by using a range object, for instance. Here's a pseudo-code of what I would do. I leave it up to you to make the necessary adjustments to make it work (because I don't see much effort in your question).

```
Function fUserName(rng as Range) as String
    fUserName = Left(Trim(rng.Offset(0, 1).value), 1) & " " & rng.Offset(0, 2).value
End Function
```

Instead of calling `fUserName()` with `rng.value`, just put in `rng`. This will use the range object to get the proper rows for B and C.

Answer (score -1):

Following code select first blank row

```
Sub SelFrstBlankRow()
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a20")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("u20")
Set r3 = Range(r1.End(xlUp), r2.End(xlUp)) 'r3 is the 1st blank row
r3.Select

End Sub
```